# How do I merge 3 files into 1 Master file on Sharepoint?

Tags: power-automate

I receive automated emails with Excel file attachments to a shared mailbox daily on weekdays.

I want to save these onto SharePoint and update the Master Checklist spreadsheet using Power Automate.

The 'AgileDDSEquityMultiCombined_yyyy-MM-dd.xlsx' are the files that I receive in the Shared Mailbox daily.

'Daybook Equity Checklist.xlsx' is the Main Workbook that I want updated.

Below, screenshot of the SharePoint folder.
[image: Screenshot of the SharePoint]

This is the overall flow. It has worked up until 'List rows present in a table'.
[image: This is the overall flow]

This is screenshot of 'Apply to each', 'Create file' and 'Get file properties' expanded.
[image: This is the 'Apply to each', 'Create file' and 'Get file properties' expanded]

This is 'Create Table' 'List rows present in a table' and 'List rows present in a table 2' expanded.
[image: This is 'Create Table' 'List rows present in a table' and 'List rows present in a table 2' expanded]

When I test the flow, this is the error message I receive.
Error message 1:
[image: Error message 1]

Error message 2:
[image: Error message 2]

Please let me know why the 'List rows present in a table 2' isn't working?
I've gone into the Sharepoint file and checked table 'DayookEquity' does exist.

Thank you

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your screenshots. Have you posted the same screenshots in some variants several times??

Comment: Hi @teylyn thank you for responding. I've updated the post to clarify the screenshots. Please let me know if there is anything else needs clarifying.